# Sequelizejs: Validation returning __raw in error

Tags: validation, sequelize.js

I created a model with validation like below:

```
sequelize
    .define('Email',
    {
        email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique:false, defaultValue: 'placeholder',
        validate: {
                isEmail: true,
            }
        }
    });
```

If I try and create an email with an empty 'email' field, it generates this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "__raw": [
            null
        ],
        "email": [
            "Validation isEmail failed"
        ]
}
```

What is the __raw field and how can I remove it?

Comment: Wondering the same thing....did you find out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this validation

```
email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            emailValidation: function() {
                var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
                if(!pattern.test(this.email)) {
                    throw new Error('INVALID_EMAIL');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: I c/p'ed your field into my model definition and still got the __raw:     { __raw: [ undefined ], email: [ [Error: INVALID_EMAIL] ] }

Comment: can you paste the code where you are inserting or updating.